# Dynamic form changes depending on chosen fields

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony

I'm creating a form in Symfony2. I want to make some dynamic things on it.

Let's say that a user chooses some category, then depending on his choice, a next list is displayed with subcategories of the chosen category. Then after choosing a subcategory, the next list of its products is displayed and then more choices related with the product etc.... How can I achieve this and how should i even start? I've got no idea since everything in symfony2 is customized for server-side actions. Doing separate forms might be useless since I then need to validate everything at once (dealing with handleRequest would be a nightmare) and store the data in the database somehow.

Any suggestions, ideas, articles, etc. ?

Comment: Start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 0):

You could send an AJAX Request with a {{path}} as URL which would be treated by symfony2 and render a json or array with the options related to the active category. I hope this is useful.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure how this would be useful. Symfony generates all the options itself and I want to do it dynamically. I could of course clean all the options from the form but it would be incredibly silly. Have all the data to load exactly the same data (a part of it) based on category?

Comment: First request, you get: category with all options (combo1) and the elements related to the selected category (combo2). On change $(category), you send the id of the chosen category with AJAX and prepare an Action to send you back the elements related to the actual category selected and fill the combo2 with js

Answer (score 0):

Here you can modify your form when you need it.

The first form contain a category, when the user select a category, the form is send (Ajax) and an event on pre_bind check if a category is set and if it's set, you add another field for sub category

For example:

```
class CategoryEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactory $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public function preBind(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        $levelOne = isset($data['categoryLevelOne']) ? $data['categoryLevelOne'] : null;

        if (!empty($levelOne)) {
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('categoryLevelTwo'));
        }

        // level n+1 ...    
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_BIND => 'preBind');
    }
}
```

In you form add the event subscriber

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new CategoryEventSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory()));
```

Comment: Nice example, appreciated!